# Retrieve filtered point cloud from Moveit Planning Scene

Tags: ros, moveit, move-group, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I added several sensor plugins into the occupancy_map_monitor of moveit.
I have a generated occupancy map which i can visualize in RViz using  /move_group/monitored_planning_scene topic

Is it possible to retrieve the filtered point cloud of the overall scene which is generated from all the  sensors?

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202242/retrieve-filtered-point-cloud-from-moveit-planning-scene/) by [Amine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20167/amine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is the `filtered_topic` what you are looking for? From [moveit.ros.org/wiki/3D_Sensors](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/3D_Sensors):

> - filtered_cloud_topic: If this parameter is specified, the filtered cloud (without robot parts) is also republished. This makes things a little less efficient but can be useful for debugging.

Edit: hm, this is only the point cloud after self-filtering, so may not be what you are after.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20167/amine/) on 2015-02-03**:
This is the filtered point cloud from one sensor, and not from all sensors.
I would like to have one topic for all filtered point clouds

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-03**:
You might also want to try and send a message to the [moveit-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/moveit-users) mailing list. But do please report back here if you get an answer there.